# Why is my CollectionChanged event null?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding, datagrid

My binding is set this way:

```
<Grid Name="motherGrid">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Name="LoadGrid" Grid.Row="0"></DataGrid>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click_1">Hello</Button>
</Grid>
```

In code behind, I set the datacontext to the VM object which contains an ienumerable list of loads

```
 motherGrid.DataContext = VM.Loads;
```

When a button is pressed, the AddLoad method is called

```
public void AddLoad(Load load)
{
   Loads.Add(load);
   if (CollectionChanged != null)
       CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(new NotifyCollectionChangedAction()));
}
```

However, the CollectionChanged event is indeed null, so the event isnever triggered.  How can I add the DataGrid to the CollectionChanged event?

Comment: If you changed your ienumerable to instead be an `ObservableCollection<Load>` these events would work without any custom coding.

Comment: Thanks Guys, changing Loads to an ObservableColleciton worked.  I would like to choose you as the correct answer if you created an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, I changed this:

```
public List<Load> Loads = new List<Load>();
```

to this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Load> Loads = new ObservableCollection<Load>();
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, it just tells a work around which might not always be possible.